# Symfony2 Unit Testing a service

Tags: symfony, testing, service, phpunit

I'm still very new to symfony and really enjoying it.

I'm at the stage where I've managed to create and setup a service, the service itself uses 2 dependencies:

- A Data API that returns json data  (this is a separate library which
  i have implemented as a service and came with its own unit tests).
- The Doctrine Entity Manager.

The service pulls the data required using the api and then loops through the data and checks to see if the data already exists, if it does it updates the existing entity and persists it, Otherwise it creates a new entity assigns the data and persists it.

I now need to write a unit test for this, i've not used PHPUnit only from symfony2 tutorials which were testing responses from a controller.

How do i go about writing a unit test for this service?
In particular mocking the data that i would normally pull from the api.
and then checks to see if the entry needs to be updated or created?

A code example would be really helpful so i can then use this as a template to create tests for other similar services that i create.

Here's the Service i want to test:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FantasyDataAPI\Client;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumParser {
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    private  $em;
    /**
     * @var Client $client
     */
    private $client;

    public function __construct( EntityManager $em, Client $client) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public Function parseData(){

        //var_dump($this);
        $stadiumData = $this->client->Stadiums();
        //var_dump($stadiumData);
        //get the Repo
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');

        $log = array();

        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            // Get the current stadium in the list from the database
            $criteria = array( 'stadiumID' => $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $currentStadium) {
                $currentStadium = new Stadium(); //no stadium with the StadiumID exists so create a new stadium

                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Added Stadium',
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            } else {
                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Updated Stadium',
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            }
            $currentStadium->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
            $currentStadium->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
            $currentStadium->setState( $stadium['State'] );
            $currentStadium->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
            $currentStadium->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
            $currentStadium->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );
            $this->em->persist( $currentStadium );
        }
        $this->em->flush();
        return $log;
    }
}
```

****** UPDATE *******
after reading ilpaijin's answer.

I've simplified the service so it no longer returns a log, i initially had this in so i could check what had been added by sending the log to a twig template in my controller, I eventually plan to have this running as a command so i can run a it via a cron job so the log bit is unnecessary.

<strike>I'm now setting the entity within my construct as i couldn't work out how to pass an entity as a injected dependency.</strike>
Now grabbing a new entity by using `createNewStadium()` method.

The Updated Service:

```
namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FantasyDataAPI\Client;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumParser {
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    private  $em;
    /**
     * @var Client $client
     */
    private $client;
    /**
     * @var Stadium Stadium
     */
    private $stadium;

    public function __construct( EntityManager $em, Client $client) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a list of stadiums using $this->client->Stadiums.
     * loops through returned stadiums and persists them
     * when loop has finished flush them to the db
     */
    public Function parseData(){
        $data = $this->client->Stadiums();
        //get the Repo
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');

        foreach ($data as $item) {
            // Get the current stadium in the list
            $criteria = array( 'stadiumID' => $item['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $currentStadium) {
                $currentStadium = $this->createNewStadium; //no stadium with the StadiumID use the new stadium entity
            }
            $currentStadium->setStadiumID( $item['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium->setName( $item['Name'] );
            $currentStadium->setCity( $item['City'] );
            $currentStadium->setState( $item['State'] );
            $currentStadium->setCountry( $item['Country'] );
            $currentStadium->setCapacity( $item['Capacity'] );
            $currentStadium->setPlayingSurface( $item['PlayingSurface'] );
            $this->em->persist( $currentStadium );
        }
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    // Adding this new method gives you the ability to mock this dependency  when testing  
    private function createNewStadium()
    {
        return new Stadium();
    }
}
```

Comment: Services are nothing more than a simple class, you should have the same aproach as with a simple PHP class.

`class StadiumParserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {}` mock em, and client and test your `parseData`.

Comment: Its the mocking i'm not sure how to do, should i create static JSON files and pass those rather than getting the data from the api?
The data from the api is likley to change over time although the data returned by it will always have the same types but the values might be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you basically need is Unit Testing the service using what is called "[Test doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html)".

This means you should mock the dependencies your service has, this way you are able to test only the service in isolation without really relying on the deps but only on a mocked version of them, with hardcoded values or behaviour.

A true example based on your real implementation isn't possible since you have tight coupled deps as `$currentStadium = new Stadium();`. You should pass deps like these in a constructor or via getter/setter in order to be able to mock it when Unit testing.

Once done it a very indicative example would be:

```
// class StadiumParser revisited and simplified
class StadiumParser 
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client) 
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function parseData()
    {
        $stadiumData = $this->client->Stadiums();

        // do something with the repo

        $log = array();

        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            $logData = [
                'action'   => 'Added Stadium',
                'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
            ];
            $log[] = $logData;
        } 

        // do something else with Doctrine

        return $log;
    }
}
```

and the test

```
// StadiumParser Unit Test
class StadiumParserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function testItParseDataAndReturnTheLog()
    {
        $client = $this->getMock('FantasyDataAPI\Client');

        // since you class is returning a log array, we mock it here
        $expectedLog = array(
            array(
                'action'   => 'Added Stadium',
                'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
            )
        );

        // this is the mocked or test double part. 
        // We only need this method return something without really calling it
        // So we mock it and we hardcode the expected return value
        $stadiumData = array(
            array(
                "StadiumID" => 1,
                "Name" => "aStadiumName"
            )
        );

        $client->expects($this->once())
            ->method('Stadiums')
            ->will($this->returnValue($stadiumData));

        $stadiumParser = new StadiumParser($client);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedLog, $stadiumParser->parseData());
    }
}
```

I voluntarily omitted the EntityManager part because I guess you should have a look at the Symfony Doc relative to [how to unit test code interacting with the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html)

---

### -----EDIT2-----

Yes he was right, you shouldn't. One possible way that comes in mind is to extract the creation of the entity in a protected/private method. Something like:

```
// class StadiumParser
public Function parseData()
{
    ...

    foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
        ...

        if ( ! $currentStadium) {
            $currentStadium = $this->createNewStadium();
        ...
}

// Adding this new method gives you the ability to mock this dependency when testing  
private function createNewStadium()
{
    return new Stadium();
}
```

---

### -----EDIT3-----

I want to suggest you another approach. This should be, probably, a better choice should the `Stadium` entity needed in different services or different part of the same. What I'm proposing is called [Builder](http://www.jakowicz.com/builder-pattern-in-php/) pattern but a [Factory](http://www.jakowicz.com/factory-pattern-in-php/) could also be an option here. Browse a bit for their differences.
As you can see this extract some code from the method, distribute better the responsibility between the classes and leaves all cleaner and easier to read for you and your teammates. And you already know how to mock it when testing.

```
class StadiumParser 
{
    private  $stadiumBuilder;
    ...

    public function __construct( StadiumBuilder $builder, ...) {
        $this->stadiumBuilder = $stadiumBuilder;
        ...
    }

    public Function parseData()
    {
        ...

        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            ...
            $currentStadium = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $currentStadium) {
                $currentStadium = $this->stadiumBuilder->build($currentStadium, $stadium);
            }

            $this->em->persist($currentStadium);
            ...
```

somewhere you have this new Builder that return a `Stadium` instance. this way your `StadiumParser` service is not coupled anymore with the entity, but the `StadiumBuilder` is it. The logic is something like:

```
// StadiumBuilder class

namespace ???

use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumBuilder 
{
    // depending on the needs but this should also has a different name
    // like buildBasic or buildFull or buildBlaBlaBla or buildTest 
    public function build($currentStadium = null, $stadium)
    {
        if (!$currentStadium) {
            $currentStadium = new Stadium();
        }

        $currentStadium->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
        $currentStadium->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
        $currentStadium->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
        $currentStadium->setState( $stadium['State'] );
        $currentStadium->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
        $currentStadium->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
        $currentStadium->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );

        return $currentStadium; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its a great help, i was told that injecting the Entity was wrong and not the right thing to do, although given no reason as to why, i'll have a bash at the unit test and see how i get on .

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any other questions about this topic please let me know, I'm here.

Comment: is it possible to inject an entity as a dependency? would i have to register the entity as a service and then inject that? or is that a big no? when building this service i wanted to initially pass the entity as a dependency, but couldnt work out how i had tried using `'::FantasyPro/DataBundle/Entity/Stadium'` but someone told me i shouldnt do this.

Comment: I updated my question as you updated yours!, is the method i used (via the constructor method) ok or would it be best to implement it using your `createNewStadium()` method?

Comment: I've used the createNewStadium method, it makes a lot more sense than setting it via my constructor.

Comment: Just added EDIT3 as a new option to consider

Comment: Thanks for the 3rd edit, it makes a lot more sense to do things this way, will have a play around and see how i get along.